# Accessing model index and send to controller with Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, soundcloud

I am building a Music Player Component with my favorites songs by SoundCloud API and Ember Cli

The Music Player is playing the audio anytime i select a song but i am trying now to play the nextFavorite once the the current song is finished.

I need to access to the favorite model index of my favorites to get the next Favorite

Here the Music controller

```
player: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.player')

actions: {
    setAsFavorite: function (favorite) {
        var favorites, favorite
        favorites = this.get('model');
        if (favorite != null) {
            this.get('player').set('favorites', favorites);
        }
        if (favorite != null) {
            return this.get('player').send('selectFavorite', favorite, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i access to the favorite index of my array favorites ?

```
return this.get('player').send('selectFavorite', favorite, 0);
```

In the code above i pass it as "0" but i need to pass this correct index of the favorite song i click as setAsFavorite

Comment: Could you provide a part of router?

Comment: I mean it's definitely pretty obvious for you how your aplication is built up. But not so easy for me atleast. Try providing less code and code that matters the most.

Comment: i have reduced the code on the function i need help, i hope it's clearer

Comment: Are you looking for http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_indexOf? Then you could do `this.get('player').send('selectFavorite', favorite, favorites.indexOf(favorite));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some minor refacto on your code. Added index of the favorite of favorites array. Also provided a way of getting next song instantly

```
actions: {
        setAsFavorite: function (favorite) {
            var favorites = this.get('model');
            var player = this.get('player');

            if (Ember.isPresent(favorite)) {
              player.set('favorites', favorites);
              player.send('selectFavorite', favorite, favorites.indexOf(favorite)); 
              // for next song 
             //  player.send('selectFavorite', favorite, favorites.nextObject(favorite)); 
            } 
        }
    }
```